# jQuery ui resizable Pass variables of resize event to stop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i need to pass variable "blabla" of resize event to stop event how can i do this?

thanks by advance here a part of the code to explain what i need:

```
.resizable({
                        disabled: disablePoignee,
                        handles: poignees,
                        resize: function (e, ui) {
                            var blabla = "pioup";
                        },
                        stop:function(e,ui){
                            //try to get blabla
                        }});
```

thanks by advance for your help

Comment: You need to help us help you. Can you share more information?

Comment: @RuiCosta I just want to pass the variable blabla to the stop function how can i explain better?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code...

```
.resizable({
  disabled: disablePoignee,
  handles: poignees,
  resize: function (e, ui) {
    var blabla = "pioup";
  },
  stop: function(e,ui) {
    //try to get blabla
  }});
```

... variable `blabla` is only available inside the function passed (as `resize` property of `options` object) into `resizable` plugin function. This value is encapsulate - essentially hidden - from the rest of the world.

To 'unhide' it, you have two options. First, make this variable external to scope of both `resize` and `stop` functions:

```
var blabla; // or const, or let
// ...
.resizable({
  resize: function (e, ui) {
    blabla = "pioup"; // note that `var` shouldn't be used here, as existing variable is reused
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    doSomethingWith(blabla);
  }});
```

That, however, won't work if there's more than one instance of `resizable` created in your code, and each of those should use its own value of `blabla`. In this case it might be useful to go with the second option - and assign some custom property to the jQuery object hosting the plugin:

```
.resizable({
  resize: function (e, ui) {
    ui.originalElement.data('blabla', 'someValue'); 
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    doSomethingWith(ui.originalElement.data('blabla')); 
  }});
```

Benefit of this approach is that data stays attached to this object even when the plugin is destroyed.

Comment: Side Note: This can also be done using `.data()`. Meaning the variable can be added to the element using `.data()` and then called up in the same way. Helpful if you have more than 1 element in play.

Comment: You mean in some other way than used in my answer?

Comment: @raina77ow thanks for your response, I had used this initially but I thought and / or I hoped that there was a clean possibility avoiding going through the dom.

Comment: @raina77ow I was looking at the first portion of your answer and didn't catch the second portion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#resizable").resizable({
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).data("foo", "bar-" + $(this).width());
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log($(this).data("foo"));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#resizable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#resizable h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Instead of creating a  more global variable, you can use [jQuery Data](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

With this, we can Set and Get data for each element. If you only have one resizable element, this is not a big deal. If you have many resizable items, this is very helpful in consolidating your script.

Comment: thanks for your response, I had used this initially but I thought and / or I hoped that there was a clean possibility avoiding going through the dom.